# Why does using the Google Places JavaScript client library return "NaN", while hardcoding in a API URL returns accurate results?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm playing around with Google's Places API and working on a mini project that returns the average ratings of local amenities (Schools, Bars, Restaurant, Cafes) based on a location searched by a user. Using the Google Places Library to query the results from JavaScript in an HTML file, I find that NaN, or Not Any Number, is being returned for ratings that should otherwise be there, as I know for a fact the area would have a number of the amenities mentioned above. Some areas will return a rating for let's say a cafe, and a gym but a NaN for bars, and vice versa for other areas. To delve into the issue a little deeper I searched the following API URL into my browser which shows all the results in an XML format that I was expecting for gyms of a particular area (Screenshot below).

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=53.309362,-6.304930600000034&radius=1000&type=gym&key=MY_API_KEY
```

However when I run a similar query through the Place's Javascript Client Library I get an NaN. Is the Client Library not on par with the Google Places API in terms of results that can be queried or am I making a mistake?

//Defining of my API KEY

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

// How I query the Client Library

```
 function getGyms(){

   //These are the laltitude and longitude values provided by the user
   $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
    $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

   var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
   console.log(Lat);

   var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
   console.log(Long);

   var gymLocation = {lat: Lat, lng: Long};

   var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   service.nearbySearch({
       location: gymLocation,
       radius: 2000,
       type: ['gym']
   }, gymCallback);
}

function gymCallback(results2, status2){
    var totalRating = 0;
    results2.forEach( function( place ) {
        totalRating += place.rating;
    });
     //Calculating the average rating from the list of gyms
     var averageRating = results2.length == 0 ? 0 : totalRating / results2.length;
     var averageRatingRounded = averageRating.toFixed(1);
     // Passing the rating to a TextBox
     var averageGymRatingTB = document.getElementById('gymAvgRating');
     averageGymRatingTB.value = averageRatingRounded;
    }
```

[image: Screenshot/ Cannot embed as reputation too low]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the api call, the problem is with how you handle the results in your code.

Some of the places have no reviews and so their rating is `undefined`.

Your code tries to add these `undefined` ratings as well at the `totalRating += place.rating;` line and thus you get `NaN` (*Not A Number*).

You could ignore those (*but also take that into account when calculating the average*)

Something like

```
function gymCallback(results2, status2) {
    var totalRating = 0,
        ratedCount = 0; // used to count how many places have a rating

    results2.forEach(function( place ) {
        if (place.rating !== undefined) {
            ratedCount++; // increase counter
            totalRating += place.rating;
        }
    });

    //Calculating the average rating from the list of gyms
    var averageRating = results2.length == 0 ? 0 : totalRating / ratedCount; // use the counter to get the average since not all results were used for the totalRating
    var averageRatingRounded = averageRating.toFixed(1);

    // Passing the rating to a TextBox
    var averageGymRatingTB = document.getElementById('gymAvgRating');
    averageGymRatingTB.value = averageRatingRounded;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, fixed that perfectly.